# Differentiating between string declaration vs char declaration

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

In some languages, single quotes are used to define characters and double quotes are used to define strings. In other languages, both single and double quotes are used to define strings.

Do languages that use single and double quotes to define strings often offer an explicit way to define a single character?

Are there any implications to not being able to specifically define a character? Is it acceptable - or desirable - to automatically optimize single character strings into characters?

Comment: You're looking for reason behind a handful of arbitrary and ancient decisions.

Comment: Depending on the language, a "single character" might not be the same type at all as a "string". So in those, it does not make sense. In languages in which they do have the same type, there is no optimization to be made.

Comment: A fair warning. I'm curious if the decisions made in decades past are still true today, and what the implications of challenging them are.

Comment: If those who voted to close the question don't mind, I'd love any comments you have on how I could better phrase this question. Should I try to better define my questions? Should I pare it down to a single question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the language has a character data type, then there is usually a way to define a character literal.

In VB.NET for example, a character literal looks like a single character string, but with the `C` suffix:

```
Dim space As Char = " "C
```

(The reason that apostrophes was not used for character literals in VB.NET, as in for example C#, is that they are used as shorthand for the REM command.)

In Javascript for example there is no character data type, so there is no way do specify a character literal. You would represent a character either as a single character string, or as the numerical character code.

Automatically optimising a single character string to a character would not likely be a good solution, unless you also make the automatic conversion back to a string if needed. In practice that would however be the same as automatically convert a single character string to a character when needed.